# Adding Excel File to Project in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, excel, selenium-webdriver

Selenium WebDriver 
Visual Studio 2015

I am trying to add an Excel File that I have existing on my computer to the Solution Explorer in my Project, but when I try to look for the existing item (or add a new item for that matter) looking for an excel file nothing related to a xlsx File exists, not sure if I am missing a nuget package I have tried to download everyting i know pertinent to the project. please help

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't add the file using the `Add Item` dialogue.

You can right click on the project in the Solution Explorer and go to `Add` and then `Existing Item` and find the file in the project directory.

or

You can just put the file in the project's folder directory, check `Show All Files` in the `Solution Explorer` panel, and then find the file, wherever you put it in the directory, right click and then go to `Include In Project`.

[image]

Comment: No problem :) you'd do this whenever you have a `existing` file that you want added to the solution/project.